# React Spinner Loading Animation / View without State?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spinner

I have a component and need to wait for the component to mount properly. Until then, I would like to show a loading animation. How could I do this in React?

I would like to do this without state, as I have many stateless components that will need that kind of functionality. Is there any efficient way to do this? If not, how would I do this with state? Have a variable `isLoading` and then in `componentDidMount` set the variable to false and have a conditional rendering in my `render()`?

Comment: What does mount properly mean in the case of this component?

Comment: So, it's a component that shows some images. The images are animated, however, it takes some time to load the animation library. The problem is that until that animation library is loaded, the images are already seen on the screen - which I don't want to do. So I would like to put a loading / spinning animation on top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, is right to use state because only the component knows when the async call is finished.

I suggest to use `'react-loading'` package.

```
import ReactLoading from 'react-loading'

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: true
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({ isLoading: false }), 2000); // do your async call
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.isLoading) { // if doing asyng things
      return <ReactLoading type={type} color={color} height='667' width='375' />; // render the loading component
    }

    return (
      <div>Content</div>
    ); 
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a prop to component, something like `loadingFinished={animationLibLoaded ? true : false}`, and then render it conditionally in component's `render()` function, like `loadingFinished ? (<AnimatedImages />) : <LoadingSpinner />)`